# (Double Integrals) Finding F(x,y) when its not given

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

for some reason, I'm having trouble figuring out how to find F(x,y) when it's not given.

For example in this context:

Finding the area of the following:
$$
D = \{(x,y) | 1 \leq x \leq 2, x^2 \leq y \leq x\}
$$

Comment: $\lvert D\rvert = 0$ because $\forall x : (1\leq x\leq 2)\to (x^2\geq x)$.  Are you sure about the (conditional) domain of $y$?

Answer (score 1):

When  you are asked to find the area of a region  $D$, then the function to be integrated is $1$ , i.e. $F(x,y)=1$, and your integral is  $$ \int \int_{D} dxdy$$

Answer (score 0):

When you are requested to find an area or a volume, the function to be integrated is simply the characteristic function of the region you should measure. That is the function that gives $1$ on that set and $0$ outside.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant $D = \{(x,y) | 1 \leq x \leq 2, \color{blue}{x \leq y \leq x^2}\}$  (because what you wrote was a null set)

Then the area is the double integral of a constant field of $1$ over that domain.

$$\begin{align}\lvert D\rvert & = \iint_D 1\operatorname d (x,y)
\\[1ex] & = \int_1^2\int_{x}^{x^2} 1\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac 5 6
\end{align}$$

Comment: That made a lot of sense, thank you so much!